# gridExtra panel plot with identical panel sizes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
df <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(40100:40129, origin = "1899-12-30"), 
  value = rnorm(30, 8)
  )

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day") + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)
  ) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df$date) + 0, max(df$date) - 0))

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day") + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)
  ) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df$date) + 0, max(df$date) - 0))
```

Let's create the plots `p1` and `p1` as shown above. I can plot these stacked on top of each other with widths that are exactly identical (zoom to full screen to make it obvious). Note that the dates line up perfectly. Code is directly below.

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = "last"))
```

Unfortunately I can't use `ggsave()` with this code chunk above so I go to the gridExtra package.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

This almost works, but notice the dates don't quite line up perfectly, in a vertical fashion comparing the top graph to the bottom graph. **So...** what's the equivalent to `rbind()`s `size = "last"` to get me two `grid.arrange`'d objects with exactly identical widths (so the dates line up properly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `grid`, the new `patchwork` library might help here. It works with ggsave and does a good job of aligning plots.

https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork

```
patchwork::plot_layout(p1 / p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution using the `egg` package which I think is included as part of `ggplot2`. I'm going to go this route to prevent having to install `patchwork`. It appears you need R 3.5+ to be able to install `patchwork`.

```
egg::ggarrange(p1, p2)
p <- egg::ggarrange(p1, p2)
ggsave(plot = p, "panel-plot.png")
```

[image: Capture.png]